# error running rails generate devise:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

When running rails generate devise:install I get a below error message. Could you please advise me on where I may have gone wrong? The devise gem seems to have been installed correctly, although there is no devise.rb in initiliazers.

Thank you!

> C:\Sites\code\omrails>rails generate devise:install
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.4/lib/devise/rai
>   ls/routes.rb:448:in raise_no_devise_method_error!': Install does not
>   respond to 'devise' method. This usually means you haven't loaded your
>   ORM file or it's be ing loaded too late. To fix it, be sure to require
>   'devise/orm/YOUR_ORM' inside 'config/initializers/devise.rb' or before
>   your application definition in 'config /application.rb' (RuntimeError)
>   from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.4/l
>   ib/devise/rails/routes.rb:211:inblock in devise_for' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.4/l
>   ib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in each' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.4/l
>   ib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:indevise_for' from
>   C:/Sites/code/omrails/config/routes.rb:2:in block in ' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
>   .13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:ininstance_exec' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
>   .13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in eval_block' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2
>   .13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:267:indraw' from
>   C:/Sites/code/omrails/config/routes.rb:1:in ' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
>   3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:inload' from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
>   3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in block in load' from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
>   3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:inload_dependency' from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
>   3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in load' from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:inblock in load_paths'
>   from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in each' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:inload_paths' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in reload!' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:inblock in updater' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
>   3.2.13/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in call' from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
>   3.2.13/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:inexecute' from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in updater' from
>   C:2:inrescue in execute_if_updated' from C:in execute_if_updated' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:inblock in module:Finisher'
>   from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in instance_exec' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:inrun' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in block in run_initializers' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:ineach' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in run_initializers' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:ininitialize!' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in method_missing' from
>   C:/Sites/code/omrails/config/environment.rb:5:in'
>
> ```
> from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
> ```
>
> 3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in require' from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
>   3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:inblock in require' from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
>   3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in load_dependency' from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
>   3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:inrequire' from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in require_environment!' from
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in' from script/rails:6:in require' from
>   script/rails:6:in'

Comment: rails destroy devise model

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and add the following to my gem file:

```
    gem 'devise', :github => 'plataformatec/devise', :branch => 'rails4'
```

Also check that you don't have any devise scope in your routes
I hope this helps you as well.